# Ignore fallback folders that don't exist in a NuGet config (MSB4018)?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, godot

I installed a "portable" .NET build of Godot that leaves behind a file `%APPDATA%/NuGet/config/Godot.Offline.Config` which defines a fallback folder in Godot's settings folder `E:/Godot/Godot_v4.0.1-stable_mono_win64/editor_data/mono\GodotNuGetFallbackFolder` (Yes, there is a backslash among the forward slashed path in the Godot Offline Config file).

The thing is, I have it on a USB drive so the file that was generated on my C drive points to a directory on my USB drive. While the Godot config file exists on my laptop everything becomes broken, the .NET namespaces can't be found, and MSBB4018 is thrown when trying to build. On my desktop, nothing is wrong and the file coexists.

Why does indexing and building break on my laptop but not on my desktop? Why, when the fallback folder isn't found, is it not just ignored like it is on my desktop? I do not want to have to delete a file every single time I close an app to make anything related to .NET development afterwards work.

Deleting the file immediately makes indexing in VS Code and Rider work, building won't error with MSB4018 and the .NET namespaces are recognized again. The config file and fallback folder paths won't show up through commands in the dotnet CLI. I've also tried using the repair tool that comes with the .NET installers and reinstalling all of my .NET SDKs entirely. Restoring with NuGet doesn't work either.